# How can I edit or manipulate the data I get in my state before rendering the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am building an app using react and redux

After navigating to a new url an API call is made and the data now exists in the containers state.

What I want to do is before using that API data in a child component (FixtureList). **I want to refactor the data. Where do I do that and how do I do that?** Below is an example of the data:

[Data Example - Please Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SApV3.png)

From the Data example you can see that we have a key called matchday. **I want to group all the objects by the matchday they are in** and then render to the front end.

**React Container**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import FixtureList from '../components/league-fixture-list';


class LeagueFixtures extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <h2>Fixtures</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {this.props.leagueFixtures.fixtures.map((fixture, index) => {
            return <FixtureList fixture={fixture} matchday={fixture.matchday} key={index}/> 
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}  
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  leagueFixtures: state.LeagueFixtures
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LeagueFixtures)
```

**React Component**

```
import React from 'react'


const FixtureList = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className="col-sm-4">
      <li className="list-group-item">
        {props.matchday}
        {props.fixture.homeTeamName} vs {props.fixture.awayTeamName}
      </li>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FixtureList;
```

At the moment I loop through all of the data in the container and print it out in my component. It works as expected but I would like to mutate the data so I can achieve a different result.

Thank you

Comment: You could use `getDerivedStateFromProps` as seen in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). Basically what you are trying to get is *derived* data, which can be computed from the original data returned from the server.
Reselect makes it really easy *plus* it caches the result, so as long as the original data does not change, the derived data is not recomputed (currently it does so in every render).

A possible implementation would be something like this: (using lodash for simplicity)

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { keyBy } from 'lodash';

const fixtures = state => state.LeagueFixtures

const fixturesByMatchDaySelector = createSelector(
  fixtures,
  (fixtures) => keyBy(fixtures, ({matchday}) => matchday),
) 

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  leagueFixtures: state.LeagueFixtures,
  fixturesByMatchDay: fixturesByMatchDaySelector(state)
})
```

Hope that helps [=

Comment: Thank you. That helped massively! Your code has condensed it down to 38 match days but with only one team playing. I wanted to show all other teams playing in that matchday too! You have helped me get on the right track though. Thanks :)

Comment: NP [= Feel free to mark the answer as correct if you think so